# mongoose - can't fetch data using find method

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Note schema defined in note.js file:
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

```
const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
  },
  date: Date,
  important: Boolean,
})

noteSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString()
    delete returnedObject._id
    delete returnedObject.__v
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)
```

and here is my notes router:

```
notesRouter.get('/', (request, response) => {
    Note.find({}).then(notes => {
        console.log(notes.length)
        response.json(notes.map(note => note.toJSON()))
    })
})
```

and my app.js:

```
app.use('/api/notes', notesRouter)
```

I did this following the fullstackopen tutorial but i stuck at this. The length of notes array in the find method is always 0. Could someone help me with this. This is the first time i coded in node.js so it's quite hard for me to figure out. Thank you very much. If this question is not clear, please tell me and i will add more information accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
noteSchema.methods = {
  toJSON() {
    return {
      id:this._id,
      content: this.content,
      date: this.date,
      important: this.important,
    }  
}
```